# How to exclude people who have multiple roles from my result set?

Tags: sql-server, amazon-redshift

I have the following request and I am not sure how this can be achieved.

Here is the sample query I have.

```sql
CASE
WHEN a.salesman = 'Y' AND a.salesmanger = 'N' AND a.store_staff = 'N' THEN 'in_store_workers'  
WHEN a.sales_manager = 'Y' AND c.store_staff = 'N' THEN 'Store Management'  
WHEN a.store_staff = 'Y' THEN 'staff_workers'  
END as roles
```

The problem here is, I need people who are in_store_workers but not when they have multiple roles. If a person is in the in_store_workers group and also in staff workers group I want to exclude him from my result set.

Can someone help me what is the best way to achieve this?

Comment: *"I have the following request"* You forgot to tell us what that request is.

Comment: I need people who are in_store_workers but not when they have multiple roles. If a person is in the in_store_workers group and also in staff workers group I want to exclude him from my result set. @Larnu

Comment: Simply repeating a vague statement does not make it more clear for others. We are horribly disadvantaged here. We don't know your data, we don't know your table, we can't see your query and have basically no idea what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: The vague answer would be "You need to use grouping and aggregate functions, most likely count. Might need to utilize having as well".

Comment: That's the statement you make after your code in your question, @SQLLeraner , it doesn't tell us what your request is (what you have been asked to do). We can't run our SQL, it's incomplete, nor can we see your data. You need to help us help you.